# Do we need to render templates when using ReactJS as a front-end?

Tags: django, reactjs, templates, rendering

So I just created a website's front-end using ReactJS. Now all I need is a backend database that I will fetch data from using requests.

The question is whether I need to render templates using my backend or just use my server to make requests (eg get, post etc)

PS. I will be using Django as my backend.

Thank you everyone who will help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Doing both is recommended. Based on the requirements and use cases we must use both ways to render.

For example, Some products use initial html as a Server side rendered page with all essential data required inserted as scripts and so on. This helps in loading primary content faster. If we are not following this in applications that require data initially. Then it might take more time to fetch React chunks, scripting and after seeing an API makes request, and then getting data and then displaying the primary content. So when a page needs more data (like **More API calls**) then server side rendering might be a good way.

For other scenarios like getting user details, All these can be done using React.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you will use DRF (Django Rest Framework) to communicate between frontend and backend. Basically you will write your own APIs in the views.py that will respond with JSON data, at least in major of cases this will be enough. So, you don't need templates, since template are really Djangos' frontend, that you will not be using at all.

But, this heavily depends on what you are doing and what is your setup.

Comment: What scenarios would you recommend using templates for?

Comment: Well, I can imagine situations where it would be easier to use Django templates in some scenarios, but I don't have that situations at the moment. From my experience sometimes it just happens that this will be easier road (or sometimes only road). But, as I said, it really depends on what are you doing. Btw, I prefer Angular and my experiences lie there.